# java String comparison in concat

Tags: java, string

```
package data;
public class A {

    String s = "maew";
        String s2 = s + "class";
        String s1 = "maewclass";
        System.out.println(s2 == s1);
    }
}
```

but both will be in string constant pool and if with same content an object is created one more reference will not get created. s2 and s1 should point to same object in string constant pool.so answer should be true why its giving false

Comment: This might be an interesting read for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029244/are-strings-created-with-concatenation-stored-in-the-string-pool

Comment: Your assumption would be true if `s` were declared `final`.

Answer (score 3):

String constant pool is an internal java feature which you should never rely on. For instance the following code will produce "true"

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "Hello";
boolean result = s1 == s2;
```

But the following code will produce "false":

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = new String("Hello");
boolean result = s1 == s2;
```

String constant pool behavior may change from one java version to another since it is an internal optimization feature. It shouldn't be relied on. In your case, I suspect because you used `String s2 = s + "class";` it did create a new instance.

**In any case any String comparison MUST be done with method `equals()` of class String**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't look at the documentation, just did my own testing and what i believe that the reason you are getting "false" is because your S2 was a result of concatenation of an object (s) and the other string.

If you run this code

```
//          String s = "maew";
        String s2 = "maew" + "class";
        String s1 = "maewclass";
        System.out.println(s2 == s1);
```

The it is indeed returning `true`. So I believe, that java is not keeping result of `Object.toString + "string"` in the stringpool.

Comment: The difference is that you have a constant expression, whereas OP doesn't. And that's why you get `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String grima = "grima";
String gri = "grima";
if (grima == gri)
    System.out.println("grima == gri"); // The message is displayed
```

Both variables refer to same "grima" in string constant pool.

```
String pndey = "pandey";
String pan = "pande";
pan = pan + "y"; // The value for pan will be resolved during runtime.
if (pndey == pan)
    System.out.println("pndey == pan"); // The 2 references are different
```

Now in the second  case if I change

`pan = pan + "y";` to `pan="pande" +"y"`, then *"pndey == pan"* message will be displayed, because the compiler resolves the literal during compilation time.

Now as per Java docs on string:

> - Literal strings within the same class (§8 (Classes)) in the same package (§7 (Packages)) represent references to the same String object (§4.3.1).
> - Literal strings within different classes in the same package represent references to the same String object.
> - Literal strings within different classes in different packages likewise represent references to the same String object.
> - Strings computed by constant expressions (§15.28) are computed at compile time and then treated as if they were literals.
> - Strings computed by concatenation at run time are newly created and therefore distinct.
> - The result of explicitly interning a computed string is the same string as any pre-existing literal string with the same contents.

You read more here: https://codingninjaonline.com/2017/09/18/stringstring-constant-pool-in-java/

Comment: Thanks Tom for the edit , being new to stackoverflow still have a lot to learn :-)

Answer (score -2):

you need to use s2.equals(s1) instead of == please go through link provided for more
[here](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/)

Comment: that's not what he's asking for - I think

Comment: This question is not about the generally correct way of comparing Strings, it is about the behaviour of the String constant pool and comparing String constants.

Answer (score -2):

**Update :**

When we create object its reference is placed in the string constant pool memory.

So in your case when program is run...

> JVM finds the variable `s2` which refers to `s + "class"` in which `s` is also referencing `maew` and will be placed in the string constant pool memory.Then it finds another variable `s1` which is referring `maewclass`.
>   JVM finds two different string references so both the variables `s2` and `s1` will not be refer for same string (say..`maewclass`).

At point when class is loaded if two same values are passed it is will refer to previous object rather creating the new one...

- `String` objects with same values will always refer to the same `String` object.

  ```
  String s = "a";
  String s2 = "a";

  System.out.println(s.equals(s2));   //-------return true
  System.out.println(s == s2);        //-------return true 


                            _____
  s   ------------------>  |     |
                           | "a" |
  s2  ------------------>  |_____|    
                              ^
                              |
                   ___________|____________
                   |        Heap          | 
                   | String Constant Pool |
                   |______________________|
  ```
- `String` objects created using new operator will be different from literals

  ```
  String s = "a";
  String s2 = new String("a");
  System.out.println(s.equals(s2));      //-------return true
  System.out.println(s == s2);           //-------return false
  ```

Comment: This question is not about the generally correct way of comparing Strings, it is about the behaviour of the String constant pool and comparing String constants.

Comment: i have changed the answer

Comment: *"JVM finds the variable `s2` which refers to `s + "class"` in which `s` is also referencing `maew` and will be placed in the string constant pool memory."* What exactly will be placed there?

Comment: when s2 will be created firstly it will refer to s and then concat to "class"..that is why it is not referring a single value

Comment: I'm not talking about the single values of `s` and `"class"`. You're just a bit unclear, why OP gets `false`. Since he seems to be new, you should be a bit more clear :).